# Decline or reject (word choice)

Tags: journals, terminology

I have recently become editor-in-chief of an open access journal (Statistica) that works on a platform provided by OJS. In the web editorial system, the word "decline" is used for what I'd normally call "reject", i.e., we "decline" a submitted paper. I don't think I have seen this elsewhere, as far as I'm aware it is always called "reject".

The meaning of the word "decline", as far as my English goes, fits here, so I don't feel confident to say that this is wrong, but it is unusual at least.

Unfortunately I can't edit all occurrences of the term in the system manually without contacting support. I'm in fact not sure whether this term comes from the original OJS platform or whether the open access publishing team at my University (Bologna, Italy) is responsible for this (non-native speakers).

My question is whether you think "decline" is just fine and correct here (even if unusual), or whether it's worth the hassle to get it changed to "reject" (this for example concerns the text in decision letter templates, i.e., it will be used in decision letters to authors unless the individual letter is manually changed).

Comment: The London Mathematical Society, where I sat on the editorial board for a while, used "reject" on the buttons in the software, but neither "reject" nor "decline" appeared in any communications with authors. The title of the letters was either "Acceptance" or "Decision", and the text would say "I regret to inform you that
we shall not be able to publish your paper" in the latter case. Once you see a few of these, you know any journal using EditFlow is rejecting your paper when you see "Decision" in the subject, so it just becomes another euphemism.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it matters much.

I just browsed through a couple rejection notices I've received (everyone thinks these are bad to receive, but here I've found a positive use for them!) - none contain the word "reject" or a derivative of that word. Instead the phrasing is things like "cannot consider further" or "suggest publication in a different journal" for a desk-rejection, along with a softening language such as "we decline a majority of manuscripts received". It's possible the word would have shown up in the submission portal someplace, but not in the emailed notices from editors.

I would focus instead on making sure your decision letters to authors are **clear about the next steps**. For example, consider language along the lines of "We will not consider a resubmission of your manuscript" rather than worrying about the distinction between declining and rejecting. I don't recall ever encountering ambiguity about this, but this is the sort of message that seems most helpful to people who ask for interpretation here on Academia.SE (especially those communicating in a language different from their native language).

@Anyon has a great link to a blog from Science about the phrasing in rejection notices: https://www.science.org/content/article/we-regret-inform-you-your-scientific-manuscripts-will-be-rejected which provides a direct response to the question asked here:

> There’s a word they’re dancing around here, and it’s “reject.” Journals will never say they reject your article, only that they’re unable to accept your article. The gentleness of that sentiment might be reassuring if it weren’t so disingenuous. I mean, “unable to accept” doesn’t technically mean your article is unacceptable, only that they lacked the ability to accept it at this time—maybe, I don’t know, their computers stopped working. But deep down you know it really means they could have accepted your manuscript, but have, in fact, chosen not to.

Comment: https://www.science.org/content/article/we-regret-inform-you-your-scientific-manuscripts-will-be-rejected

Comment: @Anyon Perfect! I've grabbed a quote from that article that directly addresses the question asked here.

Comment: It seems our rejection letter template is very blunt indeed, not using "reject" but at least "decline" in a very straight manner... interesting... I actually rather like that, because I don't think being direct is that bad.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Be a little bit careful with the direct approach. It will be considered incredibly rude for, I guess, half of the world's population, to just say "we decline to publish this paper".

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I see, so it may actually be worth the hassle to change the letter template even though not for replacing "decline" by "reject".

Answer (score 8):

"Decline" and "reject" have very similar meanings, with the former having a connotation that some sort of deliberation went into it, whereas the latter lacks any empathy. I decline to accept your low-ball offer to buy my house. A machine rejects the broken egg coming down the conveyor belt. Most people will likely consider the two words interchangeable in most circumstances.

My take is that that is probably not the hill you want to die on, though there is little harm in changing the word if you want -- "reject" *is* the more commonly used word in the publishing process. You will likely find that that is among the less consequential things you have to decide upon in your new role as editor-in-chief.

Comment: "You will likely find that that is among the less consequential things you have to decide upon in your new role as editor-in-chief." That is true, but surely one this site can help with. (+1)

Comment: Actually, my reading would be the opposite, sort of reinforcing that they are very similar. "Decline" could mean for reasons not related to the paper itself (too big a backlog).